# getting unknown characters from azure SQL server databases when storing Arabic language Text

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have tried to get Arabic text from Azure SQL Server databases

I defined many Collations for my database when creating it and they still not work.
Inserting text to the database I always add 'N' character before Arabic data .

Working with local SQL server its Ok no problems
Any Idea ?

Comment: is your column NVARVCHAR(xx) or VARCHAR(xx). It must be NVARCHAR(xx) for things to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NVARCHAR` for the column type you should have no issues. I successfully got an Arabic text into SQL Azure table (used google translate to translate "Hello World" into Arabic, so do not laugh or abuse if the words are actually other):

[image: SQL Azure Arabic]

Comment: do we have to change Collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to something else? I am using nvarchar(255) but Cyrillic letters appears as ???. If I have to change collation, does it cause any problem on the database?

Answer (score 0):

adding the N before the value (arabic) is the key
the type should be nvarchar ofcourse