# SQL Azure and the encoding - missing national characters

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I created a db in SQL Azure. Now, I test it and I see, that there is a problem with an encoding. Some characters are being represented via their ASCII variant.
See the screenhot from MS SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

As you can see, some national characters are missing, e.g. ř, č, ů, ň, ě, ď...

It must be the problem of the SQL Azure since I've never seen it before, when using MS SQL server.

How to correct it?
Thanks in advance, JiKra

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting unknown characters from azure SQL server databases when storing Arabic language Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421426/getting-unknown-characters-from-azure-sql-server-databases-when-storing-arabic-l)

Comment: Check out [this exactly the same question][1] (however with Arabic characters)!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421426/getting-unknown-characters-from-azure-sql-server-databases-when-storing-arabic-l

Comment: OK, if I understand it correctly, I need to pass the value with the 'N' prefix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From description you provided I am guessing that the issue is with database collation.

When you create Azure database in Windows Azure portal, choose **Custom Create** and then select correct **collation**

[image: Azure Database Collation]

Comment: I think that this is old portal, I dont see any dropdown list in the new portal. I see a readonly text field. Where to do this change in the new portal? also does this change cause any problem in production DB?

Answer (score 0):

Use N before your string:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES N'Příliš žluťoučký kúň'
```